# How to Trigger app when the app is closed

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

I have a problem. How can I open the application remotely when the application is closed? I want to do this for incoming calls (without Telecom). You can think like Telegram or Whatsapp. I developed the application with react native, I can do this when the application is open, but I cannot do it while it is closed. I am waiting for your help in this regard. Thanks in advance. Best regards

Comment: Which library you are using?

Comment: I am using One Signal for notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a notification library like react-native-firebase you can setup a background listener to listen to an incoming call (when you get a message/notification).
https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#receiving-messages

You can also use deep linking to open the app even if the app is killed
https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

**Edit:**
 If you send a message to your app (without the notification object) and then catch the message like this:
https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#background--quit-state-messages

and inside the background handler call the deep linking url. so after setup the deep linking url your code should look like this:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  await Linking.openURL('myapp://host');
  // then add your code here after the app is launched
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => App);
```

Sorry for my bad english an I hope it's more clear

Comment: It is necessary to click on the notification to open the application, but how can it be done without clicking on the notification?

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will give feedback after trying.

Comment: I have question. How will these codes work when the application is closed?

Comment: That's the role of the background callback handler, it listens to messages even when application is in a background or quit state.